# A real square matrix with eigenvalues have absolute value less than 1

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inner-products

The following statement is true or false.

> Suppose $A$ is an $n \times n$-real matrix, all whose eigenvalues have absolute value less than 1. Then, for any $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $||Av||\leq||v||$.

It is an entrance test question and the answer is given false. I am failing to understand why. Let $\lambda$ be an eigen value of $A$. Then it has a corresponding eigen vector $v$ and subsequently $Av = \lambda v$. Therefore, $||A v || \leq ||\lambda v||$. We can also conclude $||Av|| \leq |\lambda| ~||v||$. Is the answer is given false because of the fact that $|\lambda| < 1$ instead of  $|\lambda| \leq 1$?

Comment: This is false even if $A$ is diagonalisable. Consider $A=\pmatrix{\frac12&2\\ 0&0}$ with $v=\pmatrix{0\\ 1}$ for instance. The statement is true, however, when $A$ is normal ($AA^T=A^TA$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your reasoning would be sound, if all vectors were Eigenvectors. But consider for example
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 2 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$
We have $A e_2 = 2 e_1$, hence $\vert \vert A v \vert \vert > \vert \vert v \vert \vert$. Also, all Eigenvalues of $A$ are at most $1$ (it has only one).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just overlooked the fact that all vectors are considered and the information about eigenvalue is given to mislead us!